# Is this equation for $2^k!$ correct?

Tags: proof-writing, factorial

I couldn't find any equation for $2^k!$ so I came up with an equation that appears to work for the factorial of a power of $2$. However, I'm having problems proving it. My equation:

$$
\def\x{\times}
\def\prodf#1{\prod\limits_{n=2}^{#1}\prod\limits_{i=2}^{2^{n-1}}(2i-1)}
\def\ptwof#1{2^{2^#1-1}}
\def\foffset{\prod_{x=2^f+1}^{2^{f+1}}}
2^k! = \ptwof{k}\x\prodf{k}
$$

Induction is the obvious way to go:

$$
\begin{aligned}
k=0:&\\
&2^k!=1!=1=2^{1-1}\x1=\ptwof{k}\x\prodf{k}\qquad\checkmark\\
\text{assume}&\text{true for } k=f\\
k=f+&1:\\
&2^{f+1}!=2^f!\x\foffset=\ptwof{f}\x\prodf{f}\x\foffset\\
&_{\text{unsure if this is true; did I unpack }\prodf{f}\text{ right?}}\\
&=\ptwof{f}\x(2^f+1)\x(2^f+2)\x\cdots\x(2^{f+1})\x3^{f-1}\x5^{f-2}\x7^{f-2}\x\cdots\\
&=\quad?
\end{aligned}
$$

---

I got here because

$$(2j)! = j!\x2^k\x3\x5\x7\x\cdots\x(2j-3)\x(2j-1)\\$$

So if $n=2^k$, then we can keep using that equation to replace $j!$

After trying to do, I got

$$
\ptwof{k}\x3^{p_1}\x5^{p_2}\x\cdots
$$

by testing it out for some numbers and re-arranging stuff (ie I haven't proven this correct, but I guessed it).

The powers of the odd numbers were:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c}\hline
    \text{power} &p &p-1 &p-1 &p-2 &p-2 &p-2 &p-2 &p-3 \\ \hline
    \text{number}&3 &5   &7   &9   &11  &13  &15  &17 \\ \hline
\end{array}\cdots
$$
Where $p=k-1$ (for $k>2$; we stop when $p-j$ is $0$)

Basically, before we move $2^i$ numbers right, the $2^i$ next numbers each get the power $p-i$, where $i$ is the number of times we moved right.

For at least up to $2^{5}!$, $\displaystyle\prodf{k}$ is the formula for the multiplying by the odd numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is correct. The key point is to get the correct order for the Sylow $2$-subgroup of $S_{2^{k}},$ and you have done this. After that, the other term in your product is clearly the odd part of the order of $S_{2^{k}}.$ The proof that the order of  Sylow $2$-subgroup of $S_{2^{k}}$ is what you claim can be done by induction.  You can show that $S_{2^{k-1}} \wr S_{2}$ has odd index in $S_{2^{k}},$ and then everything follows.
Later edit in response to comment: Here's how to get the power of $2$ right without using groups (its more or less what was done in the question): for $1 \leq j \leq 2^{k-2}-1,$ the power of $2$ dividing $2j + 2^{k-1}$ is the same as the power of $2$ dividing $2j.$ 
But for $j = 2^{k-2}$ the power of $2$ dividing $2j +2^{k-1}$ is $k,$ which is one greater than the power of $2$ dividing $2^{k-1}.$ Hence the power of $2$ dividing $2^{k}!$ is the same as the power of $2$ dividing $2 \times (2^{k-1}!)^{2}.$ Then by induction this power is the $(2^{k}-1)$ power.

Comment: I haven't learned this much math yet. But at least I half understand this.

Comment: Well, congratulations on getting the order right anyway. You can do it directly without group theory, which is more or less what you have done. They key point is still to get the power of $2$ dividing $2^{k}!$ correct, and you have done that.